# How to find the subspace on which a multivariate normal distribution is concentrated?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $(X_1,X_2,X_3)^T$ be a multivariate normal distribution which is singular (that is, its variance matrix has determinant $0$).

How can we find the subspace $U \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with dimension strictly less than $3$ such that $P( (X_1, X_2,X_3)^T \in U) = 1?$.

Comment: Let $\bar X=X-E(X)$, consider $\Sigma=E\left(\bar X\bar X^T\right)$ the covariance matrix of $X$. Since $\Sigma$ is singular, there exists some nonzero vector $v$ such that $\Sigma v=0$. Thus, $E\left((v^T\bar X)^2\right)=E\left(v^T\bar X\bar X^Tv\right)=v^T\Sigma v=0$ hence $v^T\bar X=0$ almost surely, that is, $P(X\in U)=1$ where $U=\left\{x\mid v^Tx=v^TE(X)\right\}$ is an affine hyperplane since $v\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Take $3$ independent samples from this distribution $a_1,a_2,a_3\in R^3$. With probability $1$, $U=\text{span}(a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

Longer answer to determine $U$: Stack $a_1,a_2,a_3$ next to each other to obtain matrix
\begin{equation}
A=[a_1~a_2~a_3]
\end{equation}
 Since distribution is singular, $A$ will be rank definition with rank $\text{dim}(U)=r<3$ with probability $1$. Take the (skinny) singular value decomposition of $A=V_1 \Sigma V_2^*$ where diagonal singular value matrix is $\Sigma\in R^{r\times r}$. Then, subspace $U$ obeys
\begin{equation}
U=\text{range}(V_1)
\end{equation} 
where $\text{range}(V_1)$ returns span of columns of $V_1$. There are exactly $r$ columns of $V_1$ which are orthonormal. This nicely characterizes $U$.

Comment: You could take 4 samples (to confirm validity of singular hypothesis) and be on the safe side.