# Subspace of singular multivariate normal distribution

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, normal-distribution, matrix-rank

I have read in a book that if $\bf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\bf{\mu}, \Sigma)$ and if $\Sigma$ is singular, then possible values of $\bf{X}-\mu$ are constrained to lie in a subspace of $R^d$ with dimension equal to rank($\Sigma$).

What does this mean? Why the dimension of the subspace is lower than the original dimension? How to define this subspace?

If $d=2$ does it mean $X-\mu$ lie its values in $R$?

These seem to relate closely with:

[How to find the subspace on which a multivariate normal distribution is concentrated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661775/how-to-find-the-subspace-on-which-a-multivariate-normal-distribution-is-concentr).

Comment: This is perhaps easiest to think about if you transform to a basis where $\Sigma$ becomes diagonal. Then the rank deficiency is the number of zeros on the diagonal.

Comment: Is it to use $D = Q \Sigma Q'$ where $D$ and $Q$ represent eigen values and eigen vectors of $\Sigma$. Then the column space formed from eigenvectors which corresponds to non-zero eigenvalues is the subspace of $X-\mu$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.